# Specifically installing libldap-2.5.0 with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, openldap

Running PHP@7.2 which requires version 2.5.0 of this lib or I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.5.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: image not found
```

If I try the typical `brew reinstall openldap libiconv` solution, this installs 2.6.0 which PHP 7.2 won't use.

I've tried `brew install openldap@2.5.0` but that doesn't work.

How can I get the older version 2.5.0 back on my system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install PHP 7.2 from the [`shivammathur/php`](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php) tap:

(First, I recommend making a copy of `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2` as a backup, in case any non-default files have been installed there.)

```
brew uninstall php@7.2
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.2
```

Answer (score -2):

> How can I get the older version 2.5.0 back on my system?

@eComEvo you may want to improve the question by stating your system.

@fn-control-option you may want to improve your answer by providing the reader with information such as "its not a system specific issue" or the like.

Comment: These should be edits, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32948656)